# System.StringException: Invalid Id:

Tags: unit-test

I have the following private method in my controller ::

```
@TestVisible private DSLogin__c createBlankLoginInfo() {
    DSLogin__c obj = new DSLogin__c();

    obj.Name = getSalesforceName();
    obj.strDBUsername__c = '';
    obj.strSessionToken__c = '';
    obj.DSServerId__c = '';
    obj.datetimeSessionStart__c = null;
    obj.datetimeSessionEnd__c = null;

    return obj;
}
```

In my test class I have the following test method ::

```
static testMethod void createBlankLoginInfo_UnitTest() {
    DSLoginController  con = new DSLoginController();

    System.assertNotEquals(con, null);

    DSLogin__c  LoginInfo = con.createBlankLoginInfo();

    System.assertNotEquals(LoginInfo, null);
}
```

Also, DSLogin__c has the following fields ::

DB_Username__c - Text(80)

DSServerId__c - Lookup(DSServer)

datetimeSessionEnd__c - Date/Time

datetimeSessionStart__c - Date/Time

strSessionToken__c - Text(255)

and the DSServer object is defined as ::

ServerURL__c - Text(255)

I am surprised to see this failing because I have called the method already in my controller.  It all works just fine.  I am adding a test for this method now and then this message shows up as I trying to save my changes.

System.StringException: Invalid Id:

Admittedly I am new to Salesforce/Apex/VisualForce/Eclipse/JSON/jQuery and last but not least HTML5 with (or without) CSS.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening?

Thank You in advance !!

-Scott.

PS.  Full disclosure - I edited this post.  Changed DSServer_*c to DSServerId*_c within the definition of the DSLogin_*c object.  My intent with this field is to store just the record id of the DSSever*_c record/object.  Hopefully, I am doing that sort of thing right or in a 'best-practice' manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'' isn't a valid Id. Use null instead.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  But, my code has been posting up to the Salesforce server just fine until I added this particular test.  Let me give it a whirl.

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't check for id correctness; this is a runtime error. If a test doesn't cover a runtime error area, you won't know about the error until a page or trigger crashed.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I can go with it being a runtime error, but when viewing the page that is using this controller, no exceptions are thrown.  Well, let me say that I have not had my execution or usage of the page disrupted by an exception.  Now, that said, I think I will turn on debugging and look through a few runnings.  Thanks !!

Comment: Possibly a try-catch block or maybe it's not called when you think it is.